# Regex 100 - 2000 in steps of 100

Tags: regex

I'm no regex expert but I've given it a go, here's what I've come up with:

```
^([1]*[1-9]00|1000|2000)$
```

The idea is to allow 100 to 2000 inclusive in steps of 100.

I've tested it manually. It (seems) to work, but is this the best solution? Can anyone see any glaring errors?

Appreciate feedback.

Comment: I don't think this regex will match, for example, `2100`.

Comment: `[1]` is the same as `1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex is valid, just notice that `[1] == 1` . An alternative is:

```
^(1?[1-9]00|[12]000)$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/JWhLkZ/1).

If you're using server side validation, prefer int manipulation instead of regex: `if (myNumber >= 100 && myNumber <= 2000 && myNumber % 100 == 0)`

example:

```
var random = new Random(100);
int myNumber;

for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
{
    myNumber = random.Next(0, 10000);
    if (myNumber >= 100 && myNumber <= 2000 && myNumber % 100 == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{myNumber} respect the conditions.");
    }
}
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the goal is to match numbers from 100 to 2000, I don't see any trace of  10000 in OP's question.

Comment: Oops...it helps to read the entire question before answering :-) +1

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen no problem ;)

Comment: @JohnOhara in which language will you use this ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, a regex is not the best solution for such a task. Regexps are good to match arbitrary sequences of characters; you want to work with numbers and the programming language you use can probably help you more than a regex.

However, if you insist, your regex must much the integer numbers `100`, `200` ... `900`, `1000`, `1100` ... `2000`

A regular expression that matches these numbers ends in `00`. The prefix matches the integer numbers from `1` to `9`, those of two digits that have `1` as their first digit and `20`.

Put together, the regexp is:

```
([1-9]|1[0-9]|20)00
```

The pieces:

```
(            # start a group
   [1-9]         # match any digit between 1 and 9...
   |             # ... or ...
   1[0-9]        # ... match any 2-digit number that starts with 1
   |             # ... or ...
   20            # match 20
)            # end o the group
00           # match 00
```

Another regexp is:

```
(1?[1-9]|[12]0)00
```

It groups the values `1..20` in a different way.

```
(
    1?            # match 1 or nothing
    [1-9]         # match any digit between 1 and 9
    |             # ... or ...
    [12]0         # match 1 or 2 followed by 0 (i.e. match 10 or 20)
)
00           # end with 00
```

`1?[1-9]` matches the numbers between `1` and `19` except `10`. `10` and `20` are matched by `[12]0`.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation.

Comment: So instead of a regex you would do if (input >= 100 && input % 100 == 0 && input <= 2000)? Personally, I like the regex here...

Comment: I'm using it in a validator, so much easier than having to create a custom one.

Comment: I would start by checking if `input` is a number and/or convert it to a number before using it with `%`.